# Transfer NA value from one dataframe to another

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, df1 and df2, one is complete while the other has some NA values. For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame( id=c(1,2,NA,NA,5,NA), value=c(NA,10,50,30,NA,60))
df2 <- data.frame( id2=c(10,20,30,40,50,60), value2=c(15,25,35,45,55,65))
```

I want to transfer the NA values from `df1` to `df2` so that `df2` will be:

```
> df2
  id2 value2
1  10     NA
2  20     25
3  NA     35
4  NA     45
5  50     NA
6  NA     65
```

Comment: This seems a bit odd.  There's nothing tying `df1` and `df2` other than the row index, which seems rather fragile.  What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility using `is.na()` to find the position of `NA` in `df1` (`TRUE` indicating missing element):

```
idx <- is.na(df1)

    idx
        id value
[1,] FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE
[5,] FALSE  TRUE
[6,]  TRUE FALSE
```

Then we can use `idx` to replace values in `df2` by `NA`:

```
df2[idx] <- NA

   df2
  id2 value2
1  10     NA
2  20     25
3  NA     35
4  NA     45
5  50     NA
6  NA     65
```

Of course, this solution only works when the dimension of `df1` and `df2` are similar.

Answer (score 0):

Following code gives the desired output

```
df2$id2[is.na(df1$id)]<-NA
df2$value2[is.na(df1$value)]<-NA
```

This finds the rows having NA value for each column in the first data set and replaces them with NA in the second dataset.

Comment: Why include the call to `which`?  And `==T`?